# How do I style my text inside an echo?

Tags: php, html, css, echo

Part of the code is

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo "$row[firstname] $row[lastname]";
                        echo "<hr>";
                        echo "<strong>Date Referred:</strong>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;$row[cf_831]";
                        echo "<br/>";
                        echo "<strong>Date Today:</strong>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&emsp;$today"; 
                        echo "<br/>";
                    }
```

How do I style this part for example?

```
"$row[firstname] $row[lastname]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition to Sidsec9's answer: if you are afraid of stylesheets, you can also consider:

```
echo '<p style="color: red; font-size: 10pt;">' . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . '</p>';
```

You could also use styles to get rid of `&emsp;`, for example using `margin-right` or `padding-right` properties.

Comment: "Afraid of stylesheet"? Time to invest in some therapy!

Comment: I'd suggest the OP accepts [Sidsec9's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31262113/2088851), it's more pretty, uses less code, and I would prefer their solution.

Answer (score 11):

You can try

```
echo '<p class="mystyle">' . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] . '</p>';
```

Then add CSS

```
.mystyle {

}
```

Comment: New to encounter styling an echo, what is (.) for? e.g . $row[firstname] .  thanks

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP

Comment: On stackoverflow, the correct way to appreciate an answer is by accepting it. Thanking in comments is against the rules.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry shame on me

Comment: Yeah, that's an universal solution, the one I use always in such cases.

Comment: What if the case is this? echo "<select name='edu'>"; How do I put p tag or div on it. I need to put it on container for position purposes.

Comment: Do you want to create a drop-down list using `<select>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<p id="name"> '. $row[firstname] $row[lastname] .'</p>';
```

Css you only using for name alone use id else use class and use the single css for all values.
    #name
    {
     color: red;
    }

Comment: I would suggest not doing this way. Because of a `while` loop, this will cause multiple `<p id="name">` tags. `Id` should be unique in the whole HTML document.

Comment: better use class to apply styles, and Ids to uniquely identify elements.

Comment: What if the case is this?  echo "<select name='edu'>"; How do I put p tag or div on it.
I need to put it on container for position purposes.

Comment: You can set using with select tag itself and your css follows: `select[name="edu"] {
   position: relative;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in a class, and fix it with a stylesheet. I also changed the echo, you're allowed to close the PHP tag, do some HTML and then open PHP again.
`<?=$variable?>` is short echo, it is the same as `<?php echo $variable; ?>`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
    <span class="Example"><?=$row[firstname].' '.$row[lastname]?></span>
    <hr>
    <strong>Date Referred:</strong>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;<?=$row[cf_831]?>
    <br/>
    <strong>Date Today:</strong>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&emsp;<?=$today?>
    <br/>
    <?php
}
```

---

A better method would be making and html file, say `example.com`, and place `<!-- FIRSTNAME -->`,`<!-- LASTNAME -->` AND `<!-- TODAY -->` instead of the variables. Then, using php:

```
$totalResult = "";
$template_one = file_get_contents("example.html");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $item = $template_one;
    $item = str_replace("<!-- FIRSTNAME -->", $row['firstname'], $item);
    $item = str_replace("<!-- LASTNAME -->", $row['lastname'], $item);
    $totalResult.= $item; // add to totel result
)
// $today doesnt change in the loop, do it once after the loop is done:
$totalResult = str_replace("<!-- TODAY -->", $today, $totalResult);
echo $totalResult; // Now you have the result in a pretty variable
```